# What should be the way to find the polynomial asked?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Problem : Let $H(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and with degree at most 2019 which satisfies:
$$
H(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
for $x=1,2, \ldots, 2020$. Find the remainder when $H(0)+H(2021)$ is divided by 1000 . Approach: taking the odd ones we can see the $H(x)$ to be of form $A(x)(x-1)(x-3)\cdots(x-2019) + 2x^2 - 2x$ but now to find $A(x)$ we would need to solve system of $1010$ equations to get it , but i think there is more slicker way to achieve that or maybe the remainder required is not much related to the $A(x)$ term possibly.

Comment: Compare $H(x) + H(2021-x)$ with $x^2/2 + (2021-x)^2/2 - 1/2$.

Comment: I think my general approach would be: first, $H(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} - R(x)$ where $R(x) = 0$ for $x=2, 4, 6, \ldots, 2020$ and $R(x) = \frac{1}{4}$ for $x=1, 3, 5, \ldots, 2019$.  Then, to find $R(0)$ and $R(2021)$ I would use the fact that $\Delta^{2020} R(0) = \Delta^{2020} R(1) = 0$ (and compare that to $\Delta^{2020}$ of the sequence which alternates between 0 and $\frac{1}{4}$).

Comment: We can see H(1)... Are like 0,4,12... But your one is x^2/2 -1/4 which doesnt makes sense @Daniel , also what you mean by deltasymbol?

Comment: What you did may you explain @user994373

Comment: Oh right, there was a thinko in that... $R(x)$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x=1,3,5,\ldots,2019$.  And as for the delta symbol, that represents the difference operation $(\Delta f)(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$; and then $\Delta^{2020}$ is the 2020-fold iteration of that operation which works out to be equal to $(\Delta^{2020} R)(x) = R(x+2020) - \binom{2020}{1} R(x+2019) + \binom{2020}{2} R(x+2018) - \binom{2020}{3} R(x+2017) - \cdots + R(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer by user989894 gives a nice shortcut for solving the problem, I thought I would give an approach which can be useful more generally for solving problems of this type.

Here, let $F(x) := \left\lfloor \frac{x^2}{2} \right\rfloor$.  Now note that if $n$ is an integer, then
$$F(n) = \begin{cases} \frac{n^2}{2}, & n \mathrm{~is~even}; \\
\frac{n^2-1}{2}, & n \mathrm{~is~odd}.\end{cases}$$
Therefore, taking the finite difference, we have that
$$\Delta F(n) \overset{def}= F(n+1) - F(n) = \begin{cases} n, & n \mathrm{~is~even}; \\
n+1, & n \mathrm{~is~odd}.\end{cases}$$
Iterating the finite difference once more, we see:
$$\Delta^2 F(n) = \begin{cases} 2, & n \mathrm{~is~even}; \\
0, & n \mathrm{~is~odd}.\end{cases}$$
With yet another finite difference, we get:
$$\Delta^3 F(n) = \begin{cases} -2, & n \mathrm{~is~even}; \\
2, & n \mathrm{~is~odd} \end{cases} = -2 (-1)^n.$$
From here, since $\Delta [(-1)^n] = -2 (-1)^n$, it is straightforward to see that
$$\Delta^k F(n) = (-2)^{k-2} (-1)^n$$
for $k \ge 3$.  In particular,
$$\Delta^{2020} F(n) = 2^{2018} \cdot (-1)^n.$$

(Or, as a slight shortcut to these calculations, you could note that $F(n) = \frac{n^2+1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} (-1)^n.$  Therefore, for $k \ge 3$, the contribution to $\Delta^k$ from the $\frac{n^2+1}{4}$ part disappears, and we are left with $\Delta^k F(n) = \frac{1}{4} (-1)^n (-2)^k = (-2)^{k-2} (-1)^n$.)

---

On the other hand, since $H$ is a polynomial of degree at most 2019, we must have that $\Delta^{2020} H(n) = 0$.  But we also have that
$$\Delta^{2020}(H - F)(1) = (H - F)(2021) - \binom{2021}{1} (H - F)(2020) + \binom{2020}{2} (H - F)(2019) - \binom{2020}{3} (H - F)(2018) + \cdots + (H - F)(1).$$
But since we are given that $H$ and $F$ agree at $1, 2, \ldots, 2020$, this reduces to simply $H(2021) - F(2021)$.  But also, we have that
$$\Delta^{2020}(H - F)(1) = \Delta^{2020}H(1) - \Delta^{2020}H(1) = -2^{2018} - 0.$$
Therefore, $$H(2021) = F(2021) - 2^{2018} = 2042220 - 2^{2018}.$$

---

A similar calculation using $\Delta^{2020}(H - F)(0)$ will show that
$$H(0) = F(0) + 2^{2018} = 2^{2018}.$$
Thus,
$$H(0) + H(2021) = F(0) + F(2021) = 2042220$$
and the final answer is that the remainder when $H(0) + H(2021)$ is divided by 1000 is: 220.  (Was this an AIME question by the way?  Just my guess from the artificial truncation to fit into a three-digit integer.)

---

(And then, based on the fact that the corrections based on $\Delta^{2020} F$ values happened to cancel out, you might eventually be led to discover the shortcut that user989894 described.)

Sample exercise which can be solved using the same technique: suppose $P(x)$ is the unique polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ such that $P(k) = F_k$ for $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, where $F_k$ is the Fibonacci sequence.  Find the value of $P(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the given range the polynomial is equal to $x^2/2$ when $x$ is even and $x^2/2 - 1/2$ when $x$ is odd. Since exactly one of $x$ and $2021-x$ is odd and one is even, it follows that

$$H(x) + H(2021-x) = x^2/2 + (2021-x)^2/2 - 1/2$$

For every  $x=1,2,\ldots,2020$. But both sides are polynomials of degrees at most $2019$ which agree on $2020$ values; so they are equal. But now you can plug in $x=0$ and evaluate $H(0)+H(2021)$ exactly. You even see that

$$2(H(0) + H(2021)) = 2021^2 - 1 \equiv 21^2 -1 = 440 \bmod 2000$$

So dividing by two the remainder mod 1000 is 220.